# Javafx: Determine node's font size

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I want to change font size dynamically. Unfortunately, layout depends on font size. The font size is setting for root styleclass. So how can I determine what is font size for some nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Every class that extends `Labeled` has a font property. You can bind this font property to another font property and change it as you like.

You can get the node from your group and  then get its font property to do what you want.

Yes the layout is dependent on size of font. Maybe calling `sizeToScene()` of stage repeatedly may help.

Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html